# How to insert html block in Handlebars partials

Tags: handlebars.js

I use Handlebars for a simple Node.js project and I would like to insert more than *just* few variables in a partial.

I have a `layout` that contains the very basic frame of my html page (`html` and `head` tags). The pages I render are usually all the same and contain the following code:

```
{{> default/header
  help_title="This is the title of my help modal."
  help_body="<p>This is the body.</p>"
}}

<main class="vertical-center">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <!-- THE CONTENT THERE -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

{{> default/footer}}
```

Depending on the page itself, I may want not to display the header and/or the footer (and I remove the line consequently).

**My need**: I'd like to wrap the `main` part in a partial (because everything but the `<!-- THE CONTENT THERE -->` is invariant) or whatever could do the job and providing to it not only few words (like in the header) but potentially a lot of html code. And I cannot find a way to do it in the documentation. Something like this, that would basically work a bit like layouts:

```
{{> default/main
  <!-- THE RAW HTML CONTENT THERE -->
}}
```

Comment: In Angular, it's called transclusion. That's what I was searching for in regards to Handlebars, but couldn't find it. Thanks for the question. Glad I eventually found it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Handlebars supports *exactly* what you are describing in the form of [partial blocks](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html#partial-block). The default behavior of partial blocks is to render default content *if* the partial cannot be found. However, there is a special built-in helper, `@partial-block` which will inject content *into* your partial.

From the documentation:

> This block syntax may also be used to pass templates to the partial, which can be executed by the specially named partial, `@partial-block`.

Inside your partial, you will add `{{> @partial-block }}` where you want the content to be injected. In your case, your "main" partial would look like:

```
<main class="vertical-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                {{> @partial-block }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Then, the page that is calling the "main" partial would do using the block syntax with the content that is to be injected into the partial put inside of block tags:

```
{{#> main}}
    <p>THE RAW HTML CONTENT HERE</p>
{{/main}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/pd4zausu/) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer @76484!